# What does その辺でね /"sono hen de ne" means in this context ? (A conversation on airplane between 3 sisters,while they're travelling to Japan)

Tags: grammar, meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

Context : 3 sisters are traveling to Japan .When the older sister saw her 2 little sisters are arguing with each other, she said this
「**二人ともその辺でね**。日本に着く前に疲れてしまうわよ」
I don't understand what does she means exactly here ( can only guess based on context that she tells her sisters to stop arguing ,but i'm not sure )
Much thanks if anyone can explain the grammar and correct meaning here of this sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

Strictly speaking, it is the definition #2 from [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%81%AE%E8%BE%BA/):

> その程度。それくらい。「―でやめたほうがいい」

The [ね](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AD/#jn-169590) is an ending particle for assertion (def #3).

---

I'm not sure how idiomatic it is, but "you guys should stop there" may work also in English.

---

[このへん](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%AD%A4%E3%81%AE%E8%BE%BA/#jn-81093) has a similar meaning.

> ２ この程度。「―で打ち切ろう」